# how to focus on second popup, when open second popup from first popup in angular-ui-bootstrap modal directive

Tags: angularjs, focus, angular-ui-bootstrap, accessibility, angular-ui

I have on scenario, I would like to show popup on popup with accessibility complaint.

first popup is working fine, if I opened second popup from first popup still focus is remains on first popup, it not moving to second popup, can you please help m on it.

I found few reference's but those using jquery bootstrap, but I am using angular-ui-bootstrap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a code sample of the popup containers and the links you're using to open them?

Comment: Thanks Stringy, Please check below code link for your reference ..http://embed.plnkr.co/aJkqAlFidVkORZuLUs39/

Answer (score 0):

Focus will usually move through focusable items (e.g. buttons, links and inputs) in the same order they are presented in the HTML. The exception to this is when you move the focus using Javascript.

Your setup doesn't seem to send focus to the modals specifically; it reaches the first one because it's next in the HTML. But the second modal is generated differently, and so the focus can't find it because it's not added to the HTML (I think; it might just be that Plunker doesn't update index.html when the modal is created). If you turn off the CSS in the example this becomes easier to see in action.

So step 1 for you will be to make sure the content is in the HTML so the focus can reach it. Usually this would be with an append() in Javascript. The next step will be to send focus to the part of the HTML you want, instead of letting the HTML order control it.

The easiest way to send focus to where you need it is to use a link, e.g.

```
<a href="#myModal">open popup window</a>
<a href="#my2ndModal">open me</a>
```

Then make sure that your div can take focus using a tabindex attribute.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#modalHeading" id="myModal">
  <h4 id="modalHeading>Dialog Title</h4>
  ... content...
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2Heading" id="my2ndModal">
  <h4 id="modal2Heading>2nd Dialog Title</h4>
  ...content...
</div>
```

The next step is to make sure that focus remains inside the current modal while it is open, so it doesn't loop back to your "open bootstrap popup" button or other focusable items that can't be seen. This is usually done with a [keyPress handler](https://www.marcozehe.de/2015/02/05/advanced-aria-tip-2-accessible-modal-dialogs/).

The ARIA role of "document" inside the first modal div isn't necessary. I don't think it's breaking anything, it's just misleading because it tells screenreader software that you've changed from browsing an app to browsing a page. And if you use role="dialog", you've got to have an aria-labelledby attribute as well.